# Ignore certain nicknames with irssi?

Tags: irc, irssi

Is there any way to ignore certain nicks with [Irssi](http://www.irssi.org/)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

/ignore <nick> should do it for one person, but there are many more options in case you want to match more people.

From the [irssi manual](http://irssi.org/documentation/manual):

```
10.1 Manual ignoring

Irssi's ignoring options should be enough for everyone :)

/IGNORE [-regexp | -word] [-pattern <pattern>] [-replies] [-except]
        [-channels <channel>] <mask> <levels> <^levels>

    -regexp: <pattern> is a regular expression
    -word: <pattern> must match to full words
    -pattern: <pattern> must match to the message's text
    -replies: Ignore replies to nick in channels. For example
              "/IGNORE -replies *!*@*.fi PUBLIC" ignores everyone
          from Finland, but also anyone sending message
          "tofinnishnick: blahblah".
    -except: *DON'T* ignore
    -channels: Ignore only in channels
    <mask>: Either a nick mask or list of channels
    <levels>: List of levels to ignore
    <^levels>: List of levels to NOT ignore
               (/ignore -except nick notices = /ignore nick ^notices)

/UNIGNORE <ref#> | <mask>

/IGNORE without any arguments displays list of ignores.

The best match always wins, so you can have:

    /IGNORE * CTCPS
    /IGNORE -except *!*@host.org CTCPS
```

Answer (score 8):

Note that if you use `/ignore <nick>`, you must `/save` to make it stick. (This will update your config file, ruining any indentation.)

I find it easier to do this directly in `~/.irssi/config`:

```
ignores = (
  # possibly lots of other stuff
  { mask = "idiotnick";   level = "ALL"; },
  { mask = "spammernick"; level = "ALL"; }
);
```

If Irssi is running, use `/reload` to bring the changes to life.